# How can I address an “Cmake is not installed” error running docker on macOS?

Tags: macos, command-line, docker

I tried to run this https://github.com/mkhaled87/pFaces-OmegaThreads in my Mac terminal and When I entered `sh build.sh`, it showed

```
CMAKE is not installed. Please install it first.
```

I have CMAKE on my MacBook. So I don't understand what causes this bug.

```
% mkdir omega
% cd omega
% docker pull mkhaled87/omega:latest
% docker run -it -v $(pwd):/docker_shared mkhaled87/omega
#cd pFaces-OmegaThreads/
#git pull
#sh build.sh
CMAKE is not installed. Please install it first.
```

[image]

Comment: Pleas show the errors as text not images so that we can read them.

Answer (score 3):

Whether cmake is on your Mac does not matter in this instance.

You are running a docker image.

Docker runs a virtual machine that runs Linux.

You need to check what is in the Dockerfile for that image and add cmake to that.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe Cmake is not really installed. Reinstall it.

Try installing homebrew by running this command.
`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`
Enter your password.

> Dots will not show up.

If you were prompted to install Xcode Developer Tools, Run the software update that shows Xcode Developer Tools. After it's installed. Type this to install Cmake.
 `brew install cmake`
If password is prompted, type your password.

> Once again the dots will not show up. If done, press enter.

Type your code again.

Comment: the cmake tool is definitely not installed on the docker image for this sequence of commands in the Q. This is great advice for needing cmake on macOS